# ndisc: failure sending router solicitation

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I am new KDE user (migrating from a Mac) using [tuxedo OS](https://os.tuxedocomputers.com/TUXEDO-OS-2-202307061627.manifest) (ubuntu 22.04)

When I connect to some public wifi networks, my OS fails to connect. I checked the logs of NetworkManager and I found this:

```
ndisc[0x55f30b0d9450,"wlo1"]: solicit: failure sending router solicitation: Operation not permitted (1)
```

And everytime I need to restart the laptop, only then the wifi connection starts working again.

It could be that this is an issue with resolving DNS (could it?) and multiple services are trying to control `/etc/resolv.conf`.

I have a VPN service running (nordvpnd) and I have `resolvconf.service` running too. In NetworkManager.conf I don't have anything set for dns. (I have tried setting `dns=default` and turning off nordvpnd but that still doesn't help)

And lastly I don't get the WiFI authentication prompt option when I connect to a public wifi. I'd expect a prompt to pop up automatically or a button saying "login" in the notification, neither happens. Also I notice that I can't ping the default gateway.

Does anyone have any clue how to get this to work?

I also posted this question on [/r/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/15a3vti/router_solicitation_question/). Appreciate any help

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Tuxedo OS is not Ubuntu, just a Ubuntu based OS that isn't on-topic here*

Comment: Note:  If you were using a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system, there are kernel stack choices, and your experience may alter by just changing the kernel stack you elected to use at install (kernel stack choice impacts kernel modules being used; kernel modules commonly called *drivers*), but all Ubuntu ISOs are generated on the same infrastructure with the difference being only the *seed* file used to create them, there is no [Tuxedo OS seed file](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/) as its not a Ubuntu system, only Ubuntu based.